# Query mongodb database to find all value for a specific field c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I want to query mongodb database to find all value under a specific field between two dates using c#.
Can you help how to query a specific field in a collection?

---

this is my collection "Devise" and i try to query all the value of "high"

```
 public class Devise
{   
    public string parité { get; set; }
    public float low { get; set; }
    public float high { get; set; }
    public DateTime  date_observation { get; set; }

}
```

---

this is my query code

```
public class Devisedata
{
    private IMongoDatabase _database;

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<Devise>> GetDataDevise(DateTime inputDate1, DateTime inputDate2)
    {

        var collection = _database.GetCollection<Devise>("datafinance");
        var builder = Builders<Devise>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Gte("date_observation", inputDate1) &
                     builder.Lt("date_observation", inputDate2.AddDays(1));


        var list = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that by "find all value" you mean all *distinct* values from field `high`. 
If so, you could do this as example below:

```
var builder = Builders<Devise>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Gte("date_observation", inputDate1) &
                 builder.Lt("date_observation", inputDate2.AddDays(1));

var cursor = await collection.DistinctAsync<double>("high", match);
await cursor.ForEachAsync(doc => Console.WriteLine(doc));
```

See [MongoCollection.Distinct](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.2/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_Distinct.htm) and [db.collection.distinct()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) for more information.

The above snippet is tested in [C# Driver](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) v2.2.3 with [MongoDB v3.2](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production)